# How to activate subpage programmatically?

Tags: java, aem, jcr

I would like to activate `subPage` of `myPage` programmatically every time the author activates the parent page (in my case `myPage`). I use EventHandler to detect an ACTIVATE action and try to activate the `subPage` with a `replicator` as follows:

```
@Property(name = "event.topics", value = { ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC })
public class mySubPageActivator extends AbstractRepositoryService implements EventHandler {
  public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
  ReplicationAction action = ReplicationAction.fromEvent(event);
    if (action.getType().equals(ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE)) {
       Replicator repl = getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Replicator.class);
       repl.replicate(getAdminSession(), ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, subPagePath);
     }
  }
}
```

the compiler prints java.lang.NullPointerException:

23.08.2013 15:04:20.138 *WARN* [Thread-2276] org.apache.felix.eventadmin Service [myjavaClass,2921] EventAdmin: Exception during event dispatch [org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=com/day/cq/replication] | [org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler] | Bundle(myBundle[170])] (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Comment: If it is the compiler that prints that you have more serious problems :p. do you have the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the Issue. The problem was that I adapted the Replicator to the wrong resource.

Comment: What change did you make to the code to get it working?